# Rails 3.1+ nested form model not rendering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have a basketball app, where a Roster has many Players, and a Player belongs to a Roster.

Roster.rb

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
  attr_accessible :class_year, :jersey_number, :player_id, :team_id
end
```

Player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gamelogs
  belongs_to :rosters
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :active
end
```

And my view that is only rendering first part of the form, but NOT the nested one

```
<div class="well">
    <h2>New Player</h2>
    <%= simple_form_for @new_player, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
        <%=f.simple_fields_for :players do |x|%>
            <%= x.input :first_name %>
            <%= x.input :last_name %>
        <%end%>
        <%=f.input :class_year %>       
        <%=f.input :jersey_number %>
        <%=f.input :team_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => params[:id]}%>

        <div class="well">
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary icon-plus-sign btn-success', :value => "Add To Team" %>
        </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Image of it not working:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoirp.png

I am using Simple_Form 2.0 and Twitter Boot Strap. Is there something I am not seeing? I feel like this should be simple, but I can't seem to figure out why it is not rendering. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an equal sign on your fields_for block:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :players do |x| %>
```

Edit:

All of this is assuming that `@new_player == Roster.new`

I had to do this with Formtastic, so it may be similar with Simple Form.

Looking at the source, it gives you an option to pass the nested object down to the nested form:

```
def simple_fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

So try doing something like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @new_player.players.build do |x| %>
```

Comment: I am using `@new_player = Roster.new`, and your `<%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @new_player.players.build do |x| %>` in a sense where its giving me an error (rather than not rendering anything). Now Im getting an `unknown attribute: roster_id`... not sure how it's getting that. Any Ideas? Sorry, my RoR expertise is beginner to moderate.

Comment: When you created your migration for player, did you do `t.references :roster`?  It looks like `roster_id` does not exist on `players`.  You have to have the foreign key on the side of the `belongs_to`.

Comment: Also, be sure that on `Player`, you have `belongs_to :roster`.  Notice the singular roster.

Comment: Thanks Sean, you are a wizard! Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Don't do build from view. Do it from controller's 'new' action, or you will not receive errors from nested model.